# Which public key should I import in jre if I want to invoke an API generated by AM?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, api-manager, wso2-esb

as the following logs , I write a httpclient example to invoke an API generated by AM. Then here is the error logs and which public key should I import in jre?

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)


Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using default keystore, you can use the cert with alias `waso2carbon`.

Comment: I export the public key and try to import it in jre and it prompts "Keytool Error: java.lang.Exception: The input is not an X.509 certificate"

Comment: How did you export?

Comment: change .jks file to test.pem file and copy the wso2carbon context in a test.pem and import it in jre

Comment: Read this https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html

Comment: openssl s_client -connect localhost:8243.
 I run the above command and generate the https certificate. It also generates the certificate .Is the certifacte right?